# Google Actions sdk not playing audio using MediaObject

Tags: node.js, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I have tried to play audio using MediaObject, MediaObject is not playing given mp3 audio files, but i got below error message" MalformedResponse 'final_response' must be set."

```
'use strict';
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const {WebhookClient} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
const {Card, Suggestion} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
const {
  dialogflow,
  BasicCard,
  BrowseCarousel,
  BrowseCarouselItem,
  Button,
  Carousel,
  LinkOutSuggestion,
  List,
  MediaObject,
  Suggestions,
  SimpleResponse,
 } = require('actions-on-google');

process.env.DEBUG = 'dialogflow:debug'; // enables lib debugging statements

exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });
  console.log('Dialogflow Request headers: ' + JSON.stringify(request.headers));
  console.log('Dialogflow Request body: ' + JSON.stringify(request.body));

  function welcome(agent) {
    agent.add(`Welcome to my agent!`);
  }

  function fallback(agent) {
    agent.add(`I didn't understand`);
    agent.add(`I'm sorry, can you try again?`);
  }

  // // Uncomment and edit to make your own intent handler
  // // uncomment `intentMap.set('your intent name here', yourFunctionHandler);`
  // // below to get this function to be run when a Dialogflow intent is matched
  function yourFunctionHandler(agent) {
    agent.add(`This message is from Dialogflow's Cloud Functions for Firebase editor!`);
    let conv = agent.conv();
    conv.ask(new Suggestions('Suggestion Chips'));
    conv.close(new MediaObject({
      name: 'Jazz in Paris',
      url: 'https://storage.googleapis.com/automotive-media/Jazz_In_Paris.mp3',
      description: 'A funky Jazz tune',
      icon: new Image({
        url: 'https://storage.googleapis.com/automotive-media/album_art.jpg',
        alt: 'Media icon',
      }),
    }));
    conv.ask(new Suggestions(['suggestion 1', 'suggestion 2']));

  }

  // Run the proper function handler based on the matched Dialogflow intent name
  let intentMap = new Map();
  //intentMap.set('Default Welcome Intent', welcome);
  //intentMap.set('Default Fallback Intent', fallback);
   intentMap.set('PlaySongIntents', yourFunctionHandler);
  // intentMap.set('your intent name here', googleAssistantHandler);
  agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
});
```

I am getting below response

```
  "responseMetadata": {
    "status": {
      "code": 10,
      "message": "Failed to parse Dialogflow response into AppResponse because of empty speech response",
      "details": [
        {
          "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.protobuf.Value",
          "value": "{\"id\":\"ff0ee47a-9df3-46c9-97db-f6db6442179b\",\"timestamp\":\"2018-06-15T09:42:53.424Z\",\"lang\":\"en-us\",\"result\":{},\"status\":{\"code\":206,\"errorType\":\"partial_content\",\"errorDetails\":\"Webhook call failed. Error: Request timeout.\"},\"sessionId\":\"1529055750970\"}"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The error message suggests that you're not including a message that should be said in addition to the audio that you want to play. It is required to include a `SimpleResponse` along with the audio.

You're mixing Dialogflow responses and Actions on Google responses, which may be confusing the response parser. You should add a `SimpleResponse` to the `conv` object as part of your response. So that portion of the code might look something like this:

```
  function yourFunctionHandler(agent) {
    let conv = agent.conv();
    conv.ask(new SimpleResponse("Here is a funky Jazz tune"));
    conv.ask(new Suggestions(['suggestion 1', 'suggestion 2']));
    conv.close(new MediaObject({
      name: 'Jazz in Paris',
      url: 'https://storage.googleapis.com/automotive-media/Jazz_In_Paris.mp3',
      description: 'A funky Jazz tune',
      icon: new Image({
        url: 'https://storage.googleapis.com/automotive-media/album_art.jpg',
        alt: 'Media icon',
      }),
    }));
  }
```

additionally, you don't import the `Image` object as part of your `require('actions-on-google')`, which is what is causing the error when the function runs. Make sure you get all the objects you need as part of the `require`.

Comment: Thanks for your help, i have tired your solution, same error shown,  i have find out error log  ReferenceError: Image is not defined
    at yourFunctionHandler (/user_code/index.js:68:17)
    at WebhookClient.handleRequest (/user_code/node_modules/dialogflow-fulfillment/src/dialogflow-fulfillment.js:251:44)
    at exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment.functions.https.onRequest (/user_code/index.js:95:9)

Comment: Can you update your question to show the code as it is now? I was responding to the error log you indicated in your original post. Are you seeing the same error?

Comment: Please don't provide logs in the comments - update your original question, it makes it a lot easier to read the errors.

Comment: Updated answer - you're missing the Image object, which you should get as part of the `require`.